# TO arrange the data such that if the some column have no values then create a new column and add that value in that

Tags: r, data-science

I have a data frame I want to copy the STATE and paste it another column. How should I do this, please help me in solving this

```
         Market        Origin              Variety      
 1 Andhra Pradesh                                         
 2  Achanta              32                  MTU-1010 
 3   Addanki             4                 B P T 
 4   Akiveedu            2                  MTU-1010 
 5   Assam                               
 6 Amadalavalasa        60                 Paddy
```

[Full Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Jg_Z2eVkOXakhvME1ZQXh5V2M)

i want this :

```
     Market            Origin              Variety            STATE                           
     2  Achanta         32               MTU-1010         Andra Pradesh
     3   Addanki         4               B P T            Andra Pradesh
     4   Addanki         2               MTU-1010         Andra Pradesh
     6 Amadalavalasa     60               Paddy              Assam

  library(plyr)
 abc <- ddply(abc,.variables= c("Market",
                     "Origin","Variety"),
    function(t) {
      x <- t$Market
      abc <- cbind(abc,STATE = x)
    }  
       )


  ##The below code is working fine but the above code is not working according to my need
 abc <- abc[ ! ( abc$Origin =="" & abc$Variety== "") , ]
```

Comment: Is your hierarchy implied by the number of spaces at the beginning of the `Market` column? Or what are the conditions? Please try to explain the problem a bit.

Comment: Also please use `dput()` to provide your data. Thus, we can help you with the problem

Comment: @loki the condition is ,if row's column "origin"and "variety" is empty then create a new column named "STATE" and add the same name of "market" column and keep adding it in the new column until the new condition is found and if found then add the new value to it  
in the question "Andra pradesh" row passes the condition ,so i created a new column and then added the name ,same with "Assam" ..and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try:

```
df  <- data.frame(Market = c("State A", "City A", "City B", "City C", "State B", "City A"), 
                  Origin = c(NA, 32, 4, 2, NA, 60))

library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(state = if_else(is.na(Origin), Market, NULL)) %>%
  mutate(state = na.locf(state)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Origin))
```

which gives:

```
  Market Origin   state
1 City A     32 State A
2 City B      4 State A
3 City C      2 State A
4 City A     60 State B
```

Comment: @RishabhKashyap glad :) . If it helped, please [check this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I am getting error on very large data  


Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `state` must be length 36292 (the number of rows) or one, not 0

Comment: What version of `dplyr` are you using? Might be easier to debug if you submit a new follow-up question with more information about your environment and the error.

Comment: I am adding link to the question of actual data, it is working by taking small sample but not with large.

Comment: your code and loki is working on small data but not on this one i really dont know why

Comment: most likely because of operations like `group_by` you're doing on the extra columns present in the data you linked to (which is not the recommended way of sharing data).  We can't be of much help here in the comments. Please post a new question with a more suited data set and information about the versions of libraries you're using. try `sessionInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic `for` loop solution.
Let's start with some data:

```
x <- data.frame(Market = c("State A", "City A", "City B", "City C", "State B", "City A"), 
                Origin = c(NA, 32, 4, 2, NA, 60))
```

Then we create a `State Variable` and a result data frame:

```
x$State <- NA
res <- x[0, ]
```

Afterwards we loop over all rows an check the condition. For rows which have values for `Origin` the State wil be inserted.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
  if (is.na(x$Origin[i])){
    statetmp <- x$Market[i]
  } else {
    newrow <- x[i,]
    newrow$State <- statetmp
    res <- rbind(res, newrow)
  }
}
res
#   Market Origin   State
# 2 City A     32 State A
# 3 City B      4 State A
# 4 City C      2 State A
# 6 City A     60 State B
```

Comment: @loki your code is totally working as per my requirements but i am facing issue with large data files in that it just keep on repeating the same state name but on sample of 300 rows it is working fine

Comment: As far as I am concerned, this is due to the fact that in your complete data set, `Origin` is `NA` in all rows. Please change `x$Origin[i]` to another variable like `x$Variety[i]`. If this solves the problem mark an answer accepted.

Comment: Furthermore, you have to check your data more carefully. As @Aramis7d already pointed out: This Q is answered so far. You should acknowledge this by accepting one answer. In theory both methods produce the right answer. Other problems emerge, as far as I can see it from the data set you shared, from problems with data structure. Therefore, you have to dig deeper into that. Other Questions here on Stackoverflow should help with these. One tip: Try to identify small problems at a time. Other R-users will most likely have faced them in the past... and then there is an answer to find here! :)